# Angular 5: Run Constructor before beeing injected

Tags: angular, angular5, injectable

I have a file with global variables:

```
@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  public baseURL:string;
  public loginURL:string;
  public proxyURL:string;
  public servicesURL:string;

  constructor(platformLocation: PlatformLocation) {
    this.baseURL = (platformLocation as any).location.href;
    this.loginURL = this.baseURL + 'rest/login';
    this.proxyURL = this.baseURL + 'rest/proxy';
    this.servicesURL = this.baseURL + 'rest/serviceRegistry';
  }
}
```

At the moment my API-Calls fail because the variables aren't set yet. Is there a way to only inject this service when the constructor is run or do I have to use Observables?

Comment: Why don't you keep these in environment.ts?

Comment: Maybe you should make a service for API-call, then use that service ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to call _globals.baseURL and it is not set yet?

Comment: @carton: because I need to make a few calculations

Comment: Have a look at APP_INITIALIZER token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didnt solve it per se. I'm using it like this now:

```
@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  /** API URLS */
  public baseURL:string = '';
  public loginURL:string = 'rest/login';
  public proxyURL:string = 'rest/proxy';
  public servicesURL:string = 'rest/serviceRegistry';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you keep these in <kbd>environment.ts</kbd>? You can also keep different environments for `prod`, `dev` etc.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  envName: 'local',
  baseUrl: '',
  proxyUrl: '',
  servicesUrl: ''
};
```

And in your service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.server}/remaining/path`)
  }

}
```

Comment: but then this would be static and if the url changes I have to change this manually

Comment: So your API call URL itself is dynamic? From where and how are you getting those dynamic values?

Comment: we have a lot of services running (20+), they are accessed through a proxy, and the list of services with their current url is provided by the proxy

Comment: but here I only set the url of the proxy to retrieve that list